# How to find the basis for Ker($T$) of $T:P_n(R) \rightarrow P_n(R)$ given by differentiation.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

I have hard time expressing formally.

Here is my try:

let $p(x)=a_0+a_1x+...+a_nx^n$. Then $p'(x)=a_1+2a_2x+...+na_nx^{n-1}$.
Setting up matrix according to standard bases $\{1,x,...x^{n-1}\}$ , we get $$\begin{bmatrix}0&1&...\\0&0&2\\0&0&0&3\\...&...&...&...&\\...&...&...&...&n-1\end{bmatrix}$$.

Since there's a zero column, I think we can say Ker$(T)=\{1\}$.

Could someone correct it?

Comment: You surely meant that $\;\ker T=\text{Span}\,\{1\}\;$

Answer (score 3):

It is very easy to calculate this without matrices and all that:

$$T(a_0+a_1x+\ldots+a_nx^n)=a_1+2a_2x+\ldots+na_nx^{n-1}=0\iff a_1=\ldots=a_n=0\implies$$

$$\ker T=\{a\;:\;\;a\in\Bbb R\}=\text{Span}_{\Bbb R}\{1\}\;$$

Of course, instead $\;1\;$ you can choose any other non-zero scalar as a basis.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $T(p)=0$ iff $a_{i}=0$ for all $i\geq  1$. So the kernel of $T$ only consists of constant functions, which you have correctly found from the matrix form as well. So $Ker(T)=span\{1\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Your work is good (apart from a missing final zero row); now observe that the nonzero columns are linearly independent, because the matrix is in echelon form; thus the rank of the matrix is $n-1$ and therefore the dimension of the kernel is $1$. Then any nonzero polynomial in the kernel will form a basis, the simplest one is the $1$ polynomial.